# Dynkin's $\pi$ lemma

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the following

> Lemma 1.4.1 (Dynkin's $\pi$-system lemma). Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\pi$-system. Then any $d$-system containing $\mathcal{A}$ contains also the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$.

> Proof. Denote by $\mathcal{D}$ the intersection of all $d$-systems containing $\mathcal{A}$. Then $\mathcal{D}$ is itself a $d$-system. We shall show that $\mathcal{D}$ is also a $\pi$-system and hence a $\sigma$-algebra, thus proving the lemma. Consider
> $$
> \mathcal{D}^{\prime}=\{B \in \mathcal{D}: B \cap A \in \mathcal{D} \text { for all } A \in \mathcal{A}\}
> $$
> Then $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{D}^{\prime}$ because $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\pi$-system. Let us check that $\mathcal{D}^{\prime}$ is a $d$-system: clearly $E \in \mathcal{D}^{\prime} ;$ next, suppose $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{D}^{\prime}$ with $B_1 \subseteq B_2$, then for $A \in \mathcal{A}$ we have
> $$
> \left(B_2 \backslash B_1\right) \cap A=\left(B_2 \cap A\right) \backslash\left(B_1 \cap A\right) \in \mathcal{D}
> $$
> because $\mathcal{D}$ is a $d$-system, so $B_2 \backslash B_1 \in \mathcal{D}^{\prime}$; finally, if $B_n \in \mathcal{D}^{\prime}, n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $B_n \uparrow B$, then for $A \in \mathcal{A}$ we have
> $$
> B_n \cap A \uparrow B \cap A
> $$
> so $B \cap A \in \mathcal{D}$ and $B \in \mathcal{D}^{\prime}$. Hence $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{D}^{\prime}$.
> Now consider
> $$
> \mathcal{D}^{\prime \prime}=\{B \in \mathcal{D}: B \cap A \in \mathcal{D} \text { for all } A \in \mathcal{D}\} .
> $$
> Then $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{D}^{\prime \prime}$ because $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{D}^{\prime}$. We can check that $\mathcal{D}^{\prime \prime}$ is a $d$-system, just as we did for $\mathcal{D}^{\prime}$. Hence $\mathcal{D}^{\prime \prime}=\mathcal{D}$ which shows that $\mathcal{D}$ is a $\pi$-system as promised.

I am struggling to understand the bigger picture. Moreover, what is $\mathcal{D}'$ used for? Reading the proof it seems that the author claims that the work we have done earlier shows that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{D}''$ but I don't see how. Could someone re-elaborate the last paragraph?

Comment: $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal D''$ says that for any $B \in \mathcal A$ and $A \in \mathcal D$, we have $B \cap A \in \mathcal D$. This follows from the fact that $A \in \mathcal D'$.

Comment: Hi @IzaakvanDongen, thank you for the comment. I understand what you are saying but I do not understand the argument that the author is making. What is the point of proving that $\mathcal{D}'$ is a $d-$ system? Why does it matter that it is equal to $\mathcal{D}$? I just don't understand why we couldn't directly work with $\mathcal{D}''$.

Comment: If you skip straight to writing down $\mathcal D''$, then it's not obvious that $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal D''$, as far as I know (without proving some lemma to the effect of $\mathcal D = \mathcal D'$). There's not much more I can say, really - if you don't believe that, then you should sit down and see what happens when you try to prove $\mathcal D = \mathcal D''$ without considering $\mathcal D'$. This type of proof does feel strange - the idea is we're showing $\mathcal D$ has a number of increasingly strong properties by showing it's equal to the subset of elements with each property.

Comment: An example of a similar proof that comes to my mind is the proof that "a nonempty compact Hausdorff topological space with a left-continuous associative operation has an idempotent". It's from a very different area of maths, but it has the same somewhat surprising proof strategy, where you want to show a set has some strong property, and you do that by arguing that each of a chain of subsets is equal to the original set. It appears as Lemma 15 [here](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/iii/Ramsey_Theory.pdf).

Comment: The reason I think that it is obvious is that $\mathcal{D}= \mathcal{D}''$ so it must be that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{D}''$. Is this not right?

Comment: Why do you think it's obvious that $\mathcal D = \mathcal D''$? It's true, because of this proof - but this proof makes use of $\mathcal D'$ to show it's true.

Comment: How does it use $\mathcal{D}'$? We are proving that $\mathcal{D}''$ is a $d$ system (which doesn't use $\mathcal{D}'$) and by definition we know that $\mathcal{D}'' \subseteq \mathcal{D}$. So by minimality, it must be the case that $\mathcal{D}'' = \mathcal{D}$ and we know by definition that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{D}$. I might have a mistake but I think this argument is correct.

Comment: That's not correct! $\mathcal D''$ being a $d$-system doesn't imply $\mathcal D'' = \mathcal D$. You need the fact that it's a $d$-system *containing $\mathcal A$*. We defined $\mathcal D$ to be the smallest $d$-system *containing $\mathcal A$*, not just "the smallest $d$-system". So to prove a subset of $\mathcal D$ is equal to $\mathcal D$, you must prove it's a $d$-system and it contains $\mathcal A$.

Comment: I think I see now. Thank you very much. Feel free to post any of this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the fact $\mathcal D = \mathcal D'$ is exactly to prove that $A \subseteq \mathcal D''$ - indeed that statement comes down to "for any $B \in \mathcal A$ and any $A \in \mathcal D$, we have $B \cap A \in \mathcal D$". Since we know $\mathcal D = \mathcal D'$, we know that $A \in \mathcal D'$, and hence $A \cap B \in \mathcal D$, by the definition of "$A \in \mathcal D'$".

The fact that $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal D''$ is essential to proving that $\mathcal D'' = \mathcal D$. Indeed $\mathcal D$ is defined to be the smallest $d$-system containing $\mathcal A$, so to prove some set $\mathcal X \subseteq \mathcal D$ is equal to $\mathcal D$, one must prove that it's a $d$-system and it contains $\mathcal A$. If you only know that $\mathcal X$ is a $d$-system, it could be much smaller than $\mathcal D$. For example, that doesn't exclude that $\mathcal X = \{\emptyset, E\}$.

This is analogous to, for example, that if $G$ is a group and $H$ is the smallest subgroup containing $x$, then to show that $K \subseteq H$ is equal to $H$, you must show that $K$ is a subgroup *and* that $x \in K$.